# How can my python script detect a buttton click on JIRA page via API

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using a python script and JIRA rest API calls to add a new functionality. My python script is continuously running on my local machine. Is there a API call which my python script can use to detect a button click on a jira ticket. For eg: If a custom button  is clicked on a JIRA ticket, my python script which is continuously polling over all jira tickets, should get notified or should somehow know about this button click so that it can run a function. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is "Cannot detect it directly."

However, there are two different approaches:

1. You can create a Jira plugin which listens that button and call your script.
2. You can install ScriptRunner plugin and use "[Listeners](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/listeners.html)" to call Python script.

By the way, for each of above approaches; you should consider converting your Python Script to a REST API. So, you can call it easily.